# Incomplete installation on Android Studio 2022.3

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to install Android Studio 2022.3, but after the installation is complete, the first time I use the ide, I'm
informed that Android SDK (unavaliable) and Performance (intel HAXM) (unavaliable)

I'm using Windows 11 and I've even used revo uninstall to ensure removal

What could be happening so that you are not able to access these tools?

[image: enter link description here])

I downloaded the most current version from the "cmdline-tools" folder but I can't install the necessary tools for the emulator to work using sdkmanager

[image]